# How can I change an urwid.Edit's text from the 'change' signal handler?

Tags: python, urwid

I want to change an urwid.Edit's text from within its "change" signal handler. However, it doesn't do anything. Minimal working example:

```
import urwid

input_line = urwid.Edit(multiline=True)

def input_change(widget, text):
        if text.endswith("\n"):
                input_line.set_edit_text('')

urwid.connect_signal(input_line, 'change', input_change)
urwid.MainLoop(urwid.Filler(input_line)).run()
```

If you press enter, it will actually call .set_edit_text(), but the text remains the same. How do I achieve what I want?

Comment: Actually, `set_edit_text` _does_ change the text—you can see that by, e.g., logging the `edit_text` attribute immediately after. The problem is that urwid doesn't set the text until _after_ your signal handler returns. (This allows you to see both the old text, as the `edit_text` attribute, and the new text, as the `text` parameter.) Which means it immediately overwrites whatever you do…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can see in [the source](http://excess.org/urwid/browser/urwid/widget.py#L1337), the `set_edit_text` method emits your `"change"` event, and then immediately afterward, it sets the `_edit_text` to the actual value.*

You can also verify this by, e.g., logging `input_line.edit_text` immediately after your `set_edit_text` to see that you did successfully change it.

What you need to do here is subclass the `Edit` widget, and override `set_edit_text`,** not handle the `"change"` signal. Then it's easy.

For example:

```
def set_edit_text(self, text):
    if text.endswith('\n'):
        super().set_edit_text('')
    else:
        super().set_edit_text(text)
```

---

As mentioned above, there's a very good reason for a GUI framework to have events that fire before the change is applied: that gives your event handler a way to see both the current value and the new value.

Of course there's also a very good reason for a GUI framework to have events that fire *after* the change is applied.

Some frameworks provide both. For example, in Cocoa, you usually get a `fooWillChange:` message before the change, and a `fooDidChange:` message afterward. Also, in some frameworks, the "before" event gives you a way to influence how the event gets handled (replace one of its values, swallow the event so it doesn't get passed up the chain, etc.). And then there's Tkinter, which provides *some* way to do all of these different things, but they're all completely different from each other, and different from widget to widget…

Is it a bug for a framework to not have all of the possible options? Well, there's a downside to a framework being too big and too general. It's harder to develop and maintain, and, worse, harder to learn. I think urwid made a reasonable choice here. Especially since it's written in relatively simple pure Python with a class class hierarchy that makes it easy to override any behavior you don't like.

However, you could maybe call it a documentation bug that Urwid doesn't tell you which kind of signal logic is uses (immutable "before" events), and offers very little guidance on what to override to customize behavior.

---

* It's also worth noting that your `change` handler is getting called in the middle of `set_edit_text`. In urwid, calling `set_edit_text` from this handler isn't a problem, but in many other UI libraries it could lead to infinite recursion or bizarre behavior.

** You could of course monkeypatch `Edit` instead of subclassing, unless you have a particular reason to do that, I wouldn't.

Comment: Is this really the "right"/intended way of doing it, though, or is this a workaround for a bug in urwid?

Comment: @Vegard: I definitely wouldn't call it a bug in urwid. I'll edit the answer to explain why.

Comment: @Vegard: Meanwhile, my opinion on how urwid should be designed isn't all that important. If you think it should have after-event signals instead of or as well as before-event, or some way to modify the event processing (mutable event objects, return values from handlers, etc.—look at a few other GUI frameworks to see the options), or hooks instead of subclassing, etc., well, urwid is an open-source project with a mailing list and a bug tracker and so on, so you can suggest improvements.

Comment: Please support this PR if you want "after-change" event -- https://github.com/urwid/urwid/pull/214

Answer (score 4):

Here is another way to do it by overriding "keypress" and defining your own "done" signal that is emitted when you press enter:

```
class CustomEdit(urwid.Edit):
    _metaclass_ = urwid.signals.MetaSignals  
    signals = ['done']


    def keypress(self, size, key):
        if key == 'enter':
            urwid.emit_signal(self, 'done', self, self.get_edit_text()) #if you dont need a reference to the CustomEdit instance you can drop the 3rd argument
            super(CustomEdit, self).set_edit_text('')
            return
        elif key == 'esc':
            super(CustomEdit, self).set_edit_text('')
            return
        urwid.Edit.keypress(self, size, key)
```

Comment: Such a signal really ought to be included in urwid by default.